# Сервис, который имеет зависимость от CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, есть класс-сервис, который в конструкторе требует CancellationToken.

Я его могу зарегать в штатном контейнере .NET Core только с default или могу достать какой-нибудь реальный Token, который привязан к жизни приложения?

Хост создаю через CreateDefaultBuilder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34834352/5045688 Можно в DI-контейнере явно создать экземпляр нужного класса с любыми параметрами

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` может регистрировать структуры, если не старый - там был [баг со структурами](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/3857). Я не разбирался как и что пофиксили..

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Так-то да... Ну как токен дернуть в момент отключения приложения? Я просто думал, что может быть есть какой-то глобальный токен самого приложения, который можно закинуть в конструктор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй, стоит это оформить ответом.

[Utilize ASP.NET Core Application Lifetime Events](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/535d4ca7-9726-46cf-bc64-64e94ec55f6e.aspx).

В ASP.NET Core есть интерфейс `IApplicationLifetime`, который среди прочих содержит члены `ApplicationStopping` и `ApplicationStopped` - это и есть глобальные `CancellationToken`, привязанные к времени жизни приложения.

Comment: Если бы можно было написать короткий комментарий, я бы написал просто "Виват!"